# Nuxt app not installing using npx or npm in windows 10 using Git Bash

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

When I try to install Nuxt js using Git Bash in windows 10 then I'm getting the following error as shown in the below screenshot.

Node Version : 14.16.1

NPM/NPX Version: 7.13.0

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you show that log file as well? And what is your node version?

Comment: @painotpi Hey here is the log file link: https://pastebin.com/D8ccV6QE

Comment: @painotpi Node Version : 14.16.1

NPM/NPX Version: 7.13.0

Comment: Does this also happen on another laptop?

Comment: @DCodeMania does `npm init nuxt-app <proj-name>`  also fail?

Comment: `npm init nuxt-app <proj-name>`  this command is also not working @painotpi

Comment: @DCodeMania Check https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3021

Comment: @DCodeMania I think it's the node version is problem. you should upgrade or change the node version to 16